# Changing log category for grails service class

Tags: grails, logging

How would I change the logging category for the built-in log object provided to service classes in Grails?

What I mean is something like the following:

```
package com.company.service
class MyService {
    def myServiceMethod(){
        log.debug "At your service..." // <-- goes to category my.new.category
    }
}
```

I could just manually create a Logger object and explicitly choose the category then - just like you'd usually do if you were writing classes in java (ie. something like `private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger('my.new.category')`), but wanted to see if there was a way to change the category of the built-in grails log object.

Why? Because all our service classes are in a single package, but we'd like to be able to control log levels independently for each one.

Comment: You can already control the logging level per Class (e.g. Service) `debug "grails.app.services.my.whatever.package.MyService"` and `warn "grails.app.services.my.whatever.package.MyOtherService"` will set different logging levels in your `Config.groovy` for the two services. You can even change it (through code) while the application is running.

Answer (score 2):

Even if all of your services are in the same package you can still set individual logging levels per service.

For example:

```
// Config.groovy
log4j.main = {
  ...
  debug  'grails.app.services.my.whatever.package.MyService'
  warn   'grials.app.services.my.whatever.package.MyOtherService'
  info   'grails.app.services.my.whatever.package.MyFinalService'
}
```

If you really do need to you can even change them while your application is running. Here is a very simple example of how that is done:

```
Logger.rootLogger.getLogger('grails.app.services.my.whatever.MyOtherService').level = org.apache.log4j.Level.toLevel('DEBUG')
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you could set on a per-class level. Our app runs in an application server, where logging config is controlled by a global log4j xml file. So not sure this will work for us, as I don't think Log4j itself supports class names as part of the logging categories.

Comment: @GreenGiant I'm pretty sure that Log4j supports class names as a part of defining what gets logged. The Grails DSL is just a simple builder for the standard log4j format, there isn't any special magic going on that makes log4j support this only through Grails.